# Syntax Error Raised When Trying to update value with XOR in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error

I'm trying to update a column of a `salary` table in my Postgres database. The script I'm trying to use is:

```
UPDATE "LC".sex
SET sex = CHAR(ASCII('f') ^ ASCII('m') ^ ASCII(sex));
```

As this worked in MySQL. However, I got a syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ASCII"
LINE 2:  SET sex = CHAR(ASCII('f') ^ ASCII('m') ^ ASCII(sex));"
```

I tried to dig around and tried my luck with `CHR()`function and then got this:

```
function chr(double precision) does not exist
```

I've nearly given up until I tried this:

```
SELECT CHAR(ASCII('f') ^ ASCII('m') ^ ASCII('f'));
```

And that gave me the same syntax error, however, `SELECT CHAR(ASCII('f') ^ ASCII('m');` does work in Postgres. So I'm critically stumped. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` operator is for exponentiation in PostgreSQL, you'd want `#` for bitwise XOR, see [Mathematical Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE) in the fine manual for details.

So you could say:

```
update "LC".sex
set sex = chr(ascii('f') # ascii('m') # ascii(sex));
```

However, I'm a little curious about what you're trying to accomplish with all the bit wrangling. If `sex` is `'f'` then you get `'m'`; if `sex` is `'m'` then you get `'f'`; if `sex` is `null` you get `null`; if `sex` is anything else then you get nonsense:

```
=> select sex, chr(ascii('f') # ascii('m') # ascii(sex))
   from (values ('f'), ('m'), ('F'), ('M'), (null), ('X'), ('y')) t(sex);
 sex | chr 
-----+-----
 f   | m
 m   | f
 F   | M
 M   | F
     | 
 X   | S
 y   | r
(7 rows)
```

If you just want to flip the sexes then why not say so:

```
update "LC".sex
set sex = case lower(sex) when 'f' then 'm' when 'm' then 'f' else null end;
```

A minor modification will preserve case if that's an issue. That will convert anything other than `'f'`, `'F'`, `'m'`, and `'M'` to `null` but presumably that's not an issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I didn't know that. I am still transitioning to Postgresql (So far I have just learned that in Postgres, `LIKE` is case sensitive). Didn't know that you can use `case` in update query as well. Only used it before in select. I just saw this method and figured it would be cool to use. And as for your question regarding the use case, yes, I basically just need to flip the sexes.